# Find an explicit formula for the recurrence $a_n = n(a_{n-1} + a_{n-2})$ knowing that $ a_0=1$ and $a_1=2$.

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

What i've tried to do is define a formal power series such that $$A(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n \dfrac{x^n}{n!}$$ Using my recurrence relation I find that $A(x)-1-2x = x(A(x)-1)+ \displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}na_{n-2} \dfrac{x^n}{n!}$ 
I do not know how to proceed after this.

Comment: Checking, I find the factorial numbers satisfy the definition:$$a_n=(n+1)!=n(n!+(n-1)!)$$

Comment: I noticed that too. Maybe I wasn't clear enough but I am trying to find the explicit formula using the generating function.

Comment: The exponential generating function of the factorials is $\frac1{1-x}$, checking the OEIS. The EGF form matches your expression for $A(x)$, continue from there.

Answer (score 1):

Often, using exponential generating functions to solve a recurrence boils down to solving a differential equation.

You can rewrite your last sum in terms of $\int A(x)\,dx$:
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty na_{n-2}\frac{x^n}{n!}=x\sum_{n=2}^\infty a_{n-2}\frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}=x\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n}\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}=x\cdot\int A(x)\,dx$$
This gives you a differential equation in $A(x)$:
$$
A(x)-1-2x=x(A(x)-1)+x\int A(x)\,dx
$$
To make this look like a more standard first-order linear equation, let $B(x)=\int A(x)\,dx$, so 
$$
B'(x)-1-2x = x(B'(x)-1)+xB(x)
$$
then use the standard method to solve (integrating factor, etc).